# Pandas replace with dictionary doesn't work for CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

I want to replace abbreviations with full words in a single column in a csv file. The csv file has 2 columns (separated by a pipe symbol) with thousands of rows, no headers, looking like this:

```
c1109db0.wav|Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Gefahr und Risiko?
c112c091.wav|Die Gefahr wird z.B. in ein Risiko umgewandelt.
c11335c1.wav|Ein Sturz d.h. ein Fall von der Kante ist ein Risiko.
```

I created a `replacers` dictionary and want to pass it as argument of `df.replace()`.

I tried several approaches I found here on Stackoverflow, but the abbreviations still don't get replaced in the new file that's created.

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd

def write_out_abbreviations():
    """Replace abbreviations in metadata file with full words."""
    # Read file into dataframe.
    with open('/home/username/data/metadata.csv') as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['Audio_Filename', 'Segment_Text'], sep='|')
        # Create dictionary that contains abbreviations and their full words.
        replacers = {
            'bspw.': 'beispielsweise',
            'bzw.': 'beziehungsweise',
            ' ca.': ' zirka',
            'd.h.': 'das heißt',
            'Dr.': 'Doktor',
            ' ggf.': ' gegebenenfalls',
            'i.d.R.': 'in der Regel',
            ' inkl.': ' inklusive',
            'insb.': 'insbesondere',
            'Tel.': 'Telefon',
            'z.B.': 'zum Beispiel'}

        # Replace abbreviations in 'Segment_Text' column.

        # APPROACH 1:
        # df2 = df.replace({'Segment_Text': {replacers}})

        # APPROACH 2:
        # df2 = df['Segment_Text'].replace(replacers)

        # APPROACH 3:
        # df2 = df.Segment_Text.str.split()
        # df2 = df.Segment_Text.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([replacers.get(e, e) for e in x]))

        # APPROACH 4:
        # df['Segment_Text'] = df['Segment_Text'].map(replacers).fillna(df['Segment_Text'])

        # Write this dataframe to new file.
        d2f.to_csv('/home/username/data/metadata_REPLACED.csv',  # or df.to_csv...
                   header=False, index=False, sep='|')

write_out_abbreviations()
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I appreciate any hints and tips. Thank you!

Comment: Please consider providing a english sample input next time, SO is a english site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

**Sample input:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1109db0.wav': {0: 'c112c091.wav', 1: 'c11335c1.wav'},
 'Was_ist_der_Unterschied_zwischen_Gefahr_und_Risiko?': {0: 'Die Gefahr wird z.B. in ein Risiko umgewandelt.',
  1: 'Ein Sturz d.h. ein Fall von der Kante ist ein Risiko.'}})
```

**Code:**

```
replacers = {
    'bspw.': 'beispielsweise',
    'bzw.': 'beziehungsweise',
    'ca.': ' zirka',
    'd.h.': 'das heißt',
    'Dr.': 'Doktor',
    'ggf.': ' gegebenenfalls',
    'i.d.R.': 'in der Regel',
    'inkl.': ' inklusive',
    'insb.': 'insbesondere',
    'Tel.': 'Telefon',
    'z.B.': 'zum Beispiel'}

df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].str.split().map(lambda lst: ' '.join([replacers.get(word, word) for word in lst]))

# Out[158]:
# 0    Die Gefahr wird zum Beispiel in ein Risiko umg...
# 1    Ein Sturz das heißt ein Fall von der Kante ist...
# Name: Was_ist_der_Unterschied_zwischen_Gefahr_und_Risiko?, dtype: object
```

Btw. I would not include the whitespaces in the abbreviations. Rather split the whole sentence on whitespaces into a lit of words. Then provide each word of the list to a dictionary, if there is no match, use the default value.

Comment: Hmm, it still does not work on my end, unfortunately. I don't know why not, perhaps the mistake lies somewhere else. The new file is created, no error, but abbreviations are still there.

Comment: you have to set `df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[.....` I adjusted my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah of course! *face palm* Thank you for pointing this out! Now it works :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`Series.str.replace` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) using both a regex and a replacement function:

```
rx = re.compile('|'.join(replacers.keys()))
df2 = df['Segment_Text'].str.replace(rx, lambda m: replacers[m.group(0)])
```

It gives for `df2`:

```
0    Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Gefahr und Ri...
1    Die Gefahr wird zum Beispiel in ein Risiko umg...
2    Ein Sturz das heißt ein Fall von der Kante ist...
Name: Segment_Text, dtype: object
```